# MonoDroid HttpWebRequest and WebClient unreliable?

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android

I am having a lot of trouble using Webrequests in MonoDroid and getting timeouts at random. My code works fine then sometimes all requests just timeout and don't work.

I have verified the webservices used in my requests are not the problem.

Here is an example of some code that I may use to request some data from a webservice using MonoDroid:

```
bool bolOk = false;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create ("http://www.website.com/service/");
request.Timeout = 20000;
request.Credentials = gv_objCredentials;

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ()) {
    bolOk = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
}
```

As you can see it is basic stuff. I use code like the above always on another thread to the UI using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem or TaskFactory.

What I have noticed is that if the requests start timing out from my app and I plug it in to my computer then debug the app from MonoDevelop the requests work without timing out. I am not sure if this means anything. This is similar to testing the webservices from my computer using a browser on the same network as the phone. The webservices always work without any issues.

What is the best way to make Webrequests from MonoDroid?

How can I ensure my requests are always successful and won't timeout if the webservice is operating correctly?

Comment: Are you by any chance firing many requests simultaneously?  I've had issues in the past with various platforms not taking kindly to multiple simultaneous requests, though I haven't had the pleasure of hammering MonoDroid in the same fashion.

Comment: Hi Chris, Yes this could be the case. I am using this code on separate threads. Do you think I should be using sync lock wherever I to a webrequest?

Comment: If that's the case, then give it a shot so you only perform 1 request at once.  I've also had an issue where it was a maximum number of request (and maximum cumulative byte size) per main UI frame that caused an issue (due to the browser I think).  So perhaps you can try placing the requests in a queue and calling them slowly and see if that works.

Comment: Can you provide some error output and your version of Mono for Android?

I experienced intermittent failures reading responses too. I'm using RestSharp, but the error was definitely being thrown from within the Mono code. Recent updates claim to fix some errors reading chunked responses.

Comment: Production release with chunked response fix was in 4.2: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3876

Comment: Try setting `request.KeepAlive=false`; see also: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=648862#c9 https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=648862#c12

Comment: Thanks everyone. I have added the KeepAlive=false and it seems to be help with the requests completing. I now think that my problem may be related to multiple requests happening at the same time. I have asked another question and will answer back here once I come up with a solution. Here is my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147563/monodroid-activity-independent-task-queue .

Answer (score 2):

I had the Issue on Xamarin 4.2.6 and 4.2.8.

Thanks to Xamarin support, they identified the issue and suggested I targeted my build to armeabi-v7a rather than armeabi in my project properties (some multi-core processor issue described [here](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/PSA-Properly-supporting-ARM-Devices-td5711990.html))

Depending on whether you plan to support multi-core processors or not, you should check our [this post](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7013#c15) and may need to manually edit your .csproj file.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new version of Mono for Android (4.2.5) that fixes a number of bugs with the WebRequest and webRequestStream. You can check the release notes here: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/Releases/Mono_For_Android_4/Mono_for_Android_4.2.5

I suggest downloading the latest bits and check if it works. If not, please file a bug and they will surely fix it in the next version of the product.