# MonoDroid Activity Independent Task Queue?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, xamarin.android

I have a Monodroid application that does many webrequests. I am making requests from activities. Because of this I have the need for a queue to process my requests outside of my activities. This is to avoid multiple requests being made at the same time.

Because I am making my requests on another thread using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem it seems like if a user opens an activity, starts a request then goes back opens another activity and starts another request before the first request has finished the use of webrequests lock up and are no longer functional.

What would the best approach be to queue request tasks with callbacks outside of the activity or does anyone know/have an example of something similar? I think that it would need to deal with cases like explained above where the activity could be closed/destroyed before the task completes. This may mean that the task can be cancelled or the task could run but not update the UI because it no longer exists.

In my case the requests that I make are within different functions doing different things so the callbacks to update the UI are not always the same functions. Also the functions that I am using to make the requests have different parameters. I am not sure if these points make it harder/easier to create a solution to this problem but I presume that I will need to rework a lot of my code.

Comment: A few issues: Why are your WebRequests "locking up" the ThreadPool? This is probably a symptom of making requests synchronously... and approach that does not scale very well. Perhaps you should look into one of the several ways of making requests async. Also, are you sure you're not hitting the max requests per domain limit?

Comment: Yes Web Requests are locking up if I do this. And the requests are to the same domain so this is probably the case. What I have identified I probably need is some way to manage the requests over all of my activities so that they are done one at a time and if the activity is closed/destroyed any requests that are yet to complete are cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Use asynchronous methods to make your requests so that you're not hanging threadpool threads.

b) Increase the connection limit for the domains you are requesting from.

```
ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri).ConnectionLimit=10000;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any chance you could point me to an example of an async method with a webrequest? Also is it possible that the host of the domain could limit the number of concurrent connections on the server side?

Comment: Look for examples containing HttpWebRequest.BeginGetrequest. Nobody knows the policy of the website you are scraping except the owner. If you're going to hammer the site, consider asking for permission. Some sites will block you if you go too fast.